# how to define a line-breaker in css, that also impacts the tag span

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a following customized CSS

```
<style>
p.mycode {border-width:1px;border-style: dashed;}
.mycode span {
  display:block;

}
</style>
```

The html code I tested is :

```
<p class="mycode"><span style="color: blue;">select </span><span style="color: black;">1<br></span><span style="color: blue;">select </span><span style="color: black;">2</span></p>
```

Here is what I got
[image]

However, what I needed is something like following
[image]

Is there a way to do that in CSS, without modifying the html part... i don't want to add more span tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p class="mycode">
<span class="d-block">
<span style="color: blue;">select </span>
<span style="color: black;">1</span>
</span>
<span class="d-block">
<span style="color: blue;">select </span><span style="color: black;">2</span>
</span></p>

<style>
p.mycode {border-width:1px;border-style: dashed;}
.d-block {
  display:block;

}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks Shirish, it works. Is there a way to implement this feature without modifying the span tag, but only modify the css?

Comment: The <pre class="code"> is able to do this without modifying the tag, is there a similar way to do that?